# How should we handle a question related to request made by a particular small business organization Needs ( billing process software.)

Tags: discussion, support, questions, scope

This question clearly requests for [Data entry and billing software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/15025/multi-site-small-business-data-entry-and-billing-software) for his organization,so this question is not off-topic but as he clearly states in that question that there are limitations with customer personal needs.And I personally think this has to be a custom build based on what he says,so in that case How should we provide a fair & proper answer to this user,Pls Advice.

- Extremely low budget
- Needs to be easy for everyone else
- Everyone is uncomfortable with a lot of change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should not treat them special in any way.

If the requirements are narrow, so be it, maybe there will be no answer because that tool does not exist, thats fine. If the requirements are too subjective and opinion based, close it as "too opinion based".

This specific case... hmm... Not a particular good question but does it need action? Lets see what close reasons we have:

1. duplicate: No.
2. Off-topic: No.
3. Unclear: No.
4. Too broad: Unlikely, simple UI for well described complex task is sufficient.
5. Opinion based: Partially ("no one likes change"), but not enough.

I say, that question won't get an Upvote from me because I think its still a bit vague, but other than that it looks fine. Leave it be.